# Operater '*' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.RadioButton', 'int'

Tags: android, operator-keyword

Operater '*' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.RadioButton', 'int'

I'm creating an app that is for the cost of printing paper using radio buttons with a 20 paper limit.
I'm unsure as to why i'm getting this error as i'm grabbing getting the information from my EditText.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
double totalcost;
double price1 = 0.15;
double price2 = 0.45;
double price3 = 0.80;
int prints;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    final EditText prints =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.noprint);
    final RadioButton price1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rad1);
    final RadioButton price2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rad2);
    final RadioButton price3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rad3);
    final TextView totalcost =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cost);
    Button calculate =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String prints = noprint.getText().toString();
            int prints = Integer.parseInt(noprint);
            DecimalFormat tenth = new DecimalFormat("$##.##");

            if (price1.isChecked()) {
                if (prints <= 20) {
                    totalcost = price1 * prints;

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Number of prints must be less than 20", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: `price1` is defined as `final RadioButton price1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rad1);` within method `onCreate(...)` and Java does not know how to multiply an `int` with a `RadioButton`. Thus the error.

Comment: use different variable names for your `RadioButton`s

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your program, you have a naming problem. On class-level, you define an attribute

```
double price1 = 0.15;
```

but within method `onCreate(...)` you also define

```
final RadioButton price1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rad1);
```

which effectively hides the attribute. Thus, when you write

```
totalcost = price1 * prints;
```

You command java to multiply a `RadioButton` with an `int`. Since this binary operator (`*(RadioButton, int)`) is undefined in Java, you get the compiler error you got. Your intention is probably to use the attribute `price1`. A quick fix would be to expicitly use the attribute through the `this` reference:

```
totalcost = this.price1 * prints;
```

A cleaner fix would be to rename your variables so you do not hide the attribute with the local variable.